# '~' operator on short/char implicitly casts to int (C / gcc)

Tags: c, casting

With gcc's `-Wconversion` warning, It looks like chars and shorts are implicitly converted to ints.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic warn "-Wconversion"

void main(void)
{
    short i = 1;
    short j = 1;
    short k = j & ~i;
    printf("value %d\n", j);
}
```

Gives the following warning,

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:9:15: warning: conversion to 'short int' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   short k = j & ~i;
               ^
```

Casting back to a short quiets the warning `short k = j & (short)~i;` but this is a bit strange adding casts where the variable types already match.

I looked into if further and `(unsigned short)~(unsigned short)0` results in `0xffff`.
Where as `~(unsigned short)0` results in `0xffffffff`

Can anyone recommend a good way of dealing with these warnings?
*Besides disabling `-Wconversion`*.

Comment: "but this is a bit strange adding casts where the types already match." - They don't match. As you correctly say, the values are implicitly converted to int (as required by the standard) before the operations are performed, and at that point, the types no longer match. And since the types don't match, I don't see a problem with the solution you've already found (adding a cast).

Comment: Edited question, noting that the **variable** types already match. evidentally after applying the operator they dont.

Comment: Note, you can cast to quiet the warning and I checked that `gcc` at least doesn't change the assembler output with/without the cast.

Comment: @ideasman42 : I think it's not a good idea to use signed integers with bitwise operators (see ISO C 99 6.5 section §4). Concerning the warning, it's the consequence of integral promotion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the C standard [(6.5.3.3)](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.3.html), the *integer promotions* are performed on the operand of `~` and the result is of the promoted type.  The integer promotions [(6.3.1.1)](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.3.1.1.html) basically say that all integer types smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` (if `int` can represent all values of the original type) or `unsigned int` (otherwise).